# MVC 5 Using spa template cannot get to display views

Tags: knockout.js, asp.net-mvc-5, single-page-application

I'm having a problem that all my view are displayed. (no js error)
No matter what, when I go to products or home, both views are displayed and I don't understand why. Isn't ko with: supposed to restrict one view or another ?
What I missing ?

Index.cshtml

```
@section SPAViews {
    @Html.Partial("_Home")
    @Html.Partial("_Products")
}
@section Scripts{
    @Scripts.Render("~/bundles/knockout")
    @Scripts.Render("~/bundles/app")
}
```

_Home.cshtml

```
<!-- ko with: home -->
...
<!-- /ko -->
```

_Products.cshtml

```
<!-- ko with: products -->
...
<!-- /ko -->
```

products.viewmodel.js

```
function ProductsViewModel(app, dataModel) {
    var self = this;

    self.query = ko.observable();

    Sammy(function () {
        this.get('#products', function () {
            $.ajax({
                method: 'get',
                url: app.dataModel.productsUrl,
                contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
                success: function (data) {
                    console.log(data);
                    self.query(data.query);

                }
            });
        })
    });

    return self;
}

app.addViewModel({
    name: "Products",
    bindingMemberName: "products",
    factory: ProductsViewModel
});
```

home.viewmodel.js

```
function HomeViewModel(app, dataModel) {
    var self = this;

    Sammy(function () {
        this.get('#home', function () {
            console.log('home');
        });
        this.get('/', function () { this.app.runRoute('get', '#home') });
    });

    return self;
}

app.addViewModel({
    name: "Home",
    bindingMemberName: "home",
    factory: HomeViewModel
});
```

Bundles:

```
 bundles.Add(new ScriptBundle("~/bundles/app").Include(
        "~/Scripts/sammy-{version}.js",
        "~/Scripts/app/common.js",
        "~/Scripts/app/app.datamodel.js",
        "~/Scripts/app/app.viewmodel.js",
        "~/Scripts/app/home.viewmodel.js",
        "~/Scripts/app/products.viewmodel.js",
        "~/Scripts/app/_run.js"));
```

Comment: ko with does not restrict what should be visible or hidden, it only sets the context for the binding.

If you want to hide/show different parts of your page depending on the routes then you should probably handle it in the router.

Comment: that's not true if the context is null. I'm well aware of how `with` works. I think there's a missing part on the MVC 5 templates. I solved with ko templates for now. But I'm pretty sure there's a navigatorFactory missing or something.

Comment: @Bart, did you finally manage to solve this problem "properly"? I'm running into the same issue now and cannot, for the life of me, figure out how the `SPA MVC 5 template` is supposed to be used.

Comment: @SergiPapaseit I created a template observable and set it depending on route.

Answer (score 0):

This might be because of a misunderstanding about the `with` binding. [From the docs](http://knockoutjs.com/documentation/with-binding.html):

> The with binding creates a new binding context, so that descendant elements are bound in the context of a specified object.

So this merely switches context. It will still show both sections.

You're probably after [the `if` binding](http://knockoutjs.com/documentation/if-binding.html) (and corresponding [`ifnot` binding](http://knockoutjs.com/documentation/ifnot-binding.html)) which is documented as follows:

> The if binding causes a section of markup to appear in your document (and to have its data-bind attributes applied), only if a specified expression evaluates to true...

You should probably use this `if` binding and change the expression to something that evaluates to a boolean.